# How to embed an URL into Blazor page

Tags: c#, embed, blazor

what I would, is have a little window on an existing website embedded into a portion of Blazor page. I would embed more than one in this view to simplify some operations.
I don't know I explained well...

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems specific to HTML and not Blazor. You can use iFrame, just change Your URL to the URL of the website:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="Your URL" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```